# Closest Two 3D Point between two Line Segment of varied Magnitude in Different Plane

Tags: c++, math, vector

Let's say `AB1, AB2, CD1, CD2`. **AB1**&**AB2** and **CD1**&**CD2** 3D Points makes a Line Segment. And the Said Line segments are *Not in the same Plane*.

`AP` is a point Line segment **AB1**&**AB2**,
`BP` is a point Line segment **CD1**&**CD2**.

`Point1` and `Point2` Closest To each other (*Shortest distance between the two line segment*)

Now, how can I Find the said two points `Point1` and `Point2`? What method should I use?

THIS IS only partially solved... because This function does not work when Two Line is on the same plane...
Thanks to @MBo I have come across [Geometry GoldMine of Code and Explanations!](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/) They have Many Source Code Contributors! i picked one from there here it is clean and great!

```
bool CalculateLineLineIntersection(Vector3D p1, Vector3D p2, Vector3D p3, Vector3D p4, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint1, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint2)
{
// Algorithm is ported from the C algorithm of 
// Paul Bourke at http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/geometry/lineline3d/
resultSegmentPoint1 = { 0,0,0 };
resultSegmentPoint2 = { 0,0,0 };

Vector3D p13 = VectorMinus(p1, p3);
Vector3D p43 = VectorMinus(p4, p3);

/*if (p43.LengthSq() < Math.Epsilon) {
    return false;
}*/
Vector3D p21 = VectorMinus(p2, p1);
/*if (p21.LengthSq() < Math.Epsilon) {
    return false;
}*/

double d1343 = p13.x * (double)p43.x + (double)p13.y * p43.y + (double)p13.z * p43.z;
double d4321 = p43.x * (double)p21.x + (double)p43.y * p21.y + (double)p43.z * p21.z;
double d1321 = p13.x * (double)p21.x + (double)p13.y * p21.y + (double)p13.z * p21.z;
double d4343 = p43.x * (double)p43.x + (double)p43.y * p43.y + (double)p43.z * p43.z;
double d2121 = p21.x * (double)p21.x + (double)p21.y * p21.y + (double)p21.z * p21.z;

double denom = d2121 * d4343 - d4321 * d4321;
/*if (Math.Abs(denom) < Math.Epsilon) {
    return false;
}*/
double numer = d1343 * d4321 - d1321 * d4343;

double mua = numer / denom;
double mub = (d1343 + d4321 * (mua)) / d4343;

resultSegmentPoint1.x = (float)(p1.x + mua * p21.x);
resultSegmentPoint1.y = (float)(p1.y + mua * p21.y);
resultSegmentPoint1.z = (float)(p1.z + mua * p21.z);
resultSegmentPoint2.x = (float)(p3.x + mub * p43.x);
resultSegmentPoint2.y = (float)(p3.y + mub * p43.y);
resultSegmentPoint2.z = (float)(p3.z + mub * p43.z);

return true;
}
```

So Far I have Tried All these Below which works only when both Line segments have the same Magnitude...

[Link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1414285/location-of-shortest-distance-between-two-skew-lines-in-3d)
[Link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/846054/closest-points-on-two-line-segments)

I tried Calculating the centroid of both line segments and calculating the nearest Point on Segment From the midpoint. (*I know how to calculate the Closest Point line segment from another Point*)

But This only works when Both Line segments are of equal length AND each of Both the Linesegment's MidPoint is perpendicular to Each other and the centroid...

NOTE:[Visual Geometry Geogbra3D](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/np6fgkxp) for a visual representation of these Points
NOTE:`AB1CD` means From Point AB1 to Line CD(not segment)

```
AB1 =                                               (6.550000, -7.540000, 0.000000 )
AB2 =                                               (4.540000, -3.870000, 6.000000 )
CD1 =                                               (0.000000, 8.000000, 3.530000 )
CD2 =                                               (0.030000, -7.240000, -1.340000 )
PointCD1AB =                                        (3.117523, -1.272742, 10.246199 )
PointCD2AB =                                        (6.318374, -7.117081, 0.691420 )
PointAB1CD =                                        (0.029794, -7.135321, -1.306549 )
PointAB2CD =                                        (0.019807, -2.062110, 0.314614 )
Magntidue of PointCD1AB - P1LineSegmentCD =          11.866340
Magntidue of PointCD2AB - P2LineSegmentCD =          6.609495
Magntidue of PointAB1CD - P1LineSegmentAB =          6.662127
Magntidue of PointAB2CD - P2LineSegmentAB =          9.186399
Magntidue of PointCD1AB - PointAB1CD =               13.318028
Magntidue of PointCD2AB - PointAB2CD =               8.084965
Magntidue of PointCD1AB - PointAB2CD =               10.433375
Magntidue of PointCD2AB - PointAB1CD =               6.598368


Actual Shortest Point are
Point1 =                                            (0.01, 1.59, 1.48 )  
Point2 =                                            (-1.23, 1.11, 3.13 )
Magnitude of Point1 And Point2 =                     2.1190799890518526
```

For the Above Data, I used this Below Function

```
void NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfVariedLength(Vector3D P1LineSegmentAB, Vector3D P2LineSegmentAB, Vector3D P1LineSegmentCD, Vector3D P2LineSegmentCD, Vector3D Testing)

{
/* float Line1Mag = Magnitude(VectorMinus(P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB));
float Line2Mag = Magnitude(VectorMinus(P1LineSegmentCD, P2LineSegmentCD));


P2LineSegmentAB = VectorMinus(P2LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentAB);
P1LineSegmentCD = VectorMinus(P1LineSegmentCD, P1LineSegmentAB);
P2LineSegmentCD = VectorMinus(P2LineSegmentCD, P1LineSegmentAB);
P1LineSegmentAB = VectorMinus(P1LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentAB);    

Vector3D P1P2UnitDirection = GetUnitVector(P2LineSegmentAB, { 0,0,0 });

AngleBetweenTwoVectorsWithCommonUnitVectorAngleOfSecondArgument(P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB, P1P2UnitDirection);*/

Vector3D ReturnVal;
Vector3D PointCD1AB;
Vector3D PointCD2AB;
Vector3D PointAB1CD;
Vector3D PointAB2CD;
NearestPointOnLineFromPoint(P1LineSegmentCD, P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB, PointCD1AB, false);
PrintVector3Dfor(VectorMinus(PointCD1AB, Testing), "PointCD1AB", true);
NearestPointOnLineFromPoint(P2LineSegmentCD, P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB, PointCD2AB, false);
PrintVector3Dfor(VectorMinus(PointCD2AB, Testing), "PointCD2AB", true);

NearestPointOnLineFromPoint(P1LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentCD, P2LineSegmentCD, PointAB1CD, false);
PrintVector3Dfor(VectorMinus(PointAB1CD, Testing), "PointAB1CD", true);
NearestPointOnLineFromPoint(P2LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentCD, P2LineSegmentCD, PointAB2CD, false);
PrintVector3Dfor(VectorMinus(PointAB2CD, Testing), "PointAB2CD", true);

float m1 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointCD1AB, P1LineSegmentCD));
float m2 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointCD2AB, P2LineSegmentCD));
float m3 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointAB1CD, P1LineSegmentAB));
float m4 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointAB1CD, P2LineSegmentAB));
float m5 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointCD1AB, PointAB1CD));
float m6 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointCD2AB, PointAB2CD));
float m7 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointCD1AB, PointAB2CD));
float m8 = Magnitude(VectorMinus(PointCD2AB, PointAB1CD));
Printfloatfor(m1, "Magntidue of PointCD1AB - P1LineSegmentCD");
Printfloatfor(m2, "Magntidue of PointCD2AB - P2LineSegmentCD");
Printfloatfor(m3, "Magntidue of PointAB1CD - P1LineSegmentAB");
Printfloatfor(m4, "Magntidue of PointAB2CD - P2LineSegmentAB");
Printfloatfor(m5, "Magntidue of PointCD1AB - PointAB1CD");
Printfloatfor(m6, "Magntidue of PointCD2AB - PointAB2CD");
Printfloatfor(m7, "Magntidue of PointCD1AB - PointAB2CD");
Printfloatfor(m8, "Magntidue of PointCD2AB - PointAB1CD");

//NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfSameLength1(P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentCD, P2LineSegmentCD);
//NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfSameLength2(P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentCD, P2LineSegmentCD);
//NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfSameLength3(P1LineSegmentAB, P2LineSegmentAB, P1LineSegmentCD, P2LineSegmentCD);
}

void NearestPointOnLineFromPoint(Vector3D Point, Vector3D LineSegmentStart, Vector3D LineSegmentEnd, Vector3D& ReturnVector, bool ClampTheValue)
{
//Get Heading Direction of Capsule from Origin To End
Vector3D CapsuleHeading = VectorMinus(LineSegmentEnd, LineSegmentStart);
float MagnitudeOfLineSegment = Magnitude(CapsuleHeading);
CapsuleHeading = VectorDivide(CapsuleHeading, MagnitudeOfLineSegment);

// Project From Point to Origin
Vector3D Projection = VectorMinus(Point, LineSegmentStart);

float DotProd = DotProduct(Projection, CapsuleHeading);
if (ClampTheValue)
{
    DotProd = Clamp(DotProd, 0.0f, MagnitudeOfLineSegment);
}   

ReturnVector = VectorAdd(LineSegmentStart, VectorMultiply(CapsuleHeading, DotProd));
}
```

I have Converted [This Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38637542/finding-the-shortest-distance-between-two-3d-line-segments/38640244#38640244) from C# to C++ and it is not working as intended... I don't know if there is a problem with my code conversion or a problem within the code itself?

```
Vector3D ClampPointToLine(Vector3D pointToClamp, Vector3D LineStart, Vector3D LineEnd)
{
Vector3D clampedPoint = {0,0,0};
double minX, minY, minZ, maxX, maxY, maxZ;
if (LineStart.x <= LineEnd.x)
{
    minX = LineStart.x;
    maxX = LineEnd.x;
}
else
{
    minX = LineEnd.x;
    maxX = LineStart.x;
}
if (LineStart.y <= LineEnd.y)
{
    minY = LineStart.y;
    maxY = LineEnd.y;
}
else
{
    minY = LineEnd.y;
    maxY = LineStart.y;
}
if (LineStart.z <= LineEnd.z)
{
    minZ = LineStart.z;
    maxZ = LineEnd.z;
}
else
{
    minZ = LineEnd.z;
    maxZ = LineStart.z;
}
clampedPoint.x = (pointToClamp.x < minX) ? minX : (pointToClamp.x > maxX) ? maxX : pointToClamp.x;
clampedPoint.y = (pointToClamp.y < minY) ? minY : (pointToClamp.y > maxY) ? maxY : pointToClamp.y;
clampedPoint.z = (pointToClamp.z < minZ) ? minZ : (pointToClamp.z > maxZ) ? maxZ : pointToClamp.z;
return clampedPoint;
}

void distBetweenLines(Vector3D p1, Vector3D p2, Vector3D p3, Vector3D p4, Vector3D& ClosestPointOnLineP1P2, Vector3D& ClosestPointOnLineP3P4)
{
Vector3D d1;
Vector3D d2;
d1 = VectorMinus(p2, p1);
d2 = VectorMinus(p4, p3);
double eq1nCoeff = (d1.x * d2.x) + (d1.y * d2.y) + (d1.z * d2.z);
double eq1mCoeff = (-(powf(d1.x, 2)) - (powf(d1.y, 2)) - (powf(d1.z, 2)));
double eq1Const = ((d1.x * p3.x) - (d1.x * p1.x) + (d1.y * p3.y) - (d1.y * p1.y) + (d1.z * p3.z) - (d1.z * p1.z));
double eq2nCoeff = ((powf(d2.x, 2)) + (powf(d2.y, 2)) + (powf(d2.z, 2)));
double eq2mCoeff = -(d1.x * d2.x) - (d1.y * d2.y) - (d1.z * d2.z);
double eq2Const = ((d2.x * p3.x) - (d2.x * p1.x) + (d2.y * p3.y) - (d2.y * p2.y) + (d2.z * p3.z) - (d2.z * p1.z));
double M[2][3] = { { eq1nCoeff, eq1mCoeff, -eq1Const }, { eq2nCoeff, eq2mCoeff, -eq2Const } };
int rowCount = 2;


// pivoting
for (int col = 0; col + 1 < rowCount; col++) if (M[col, col] == 0)
    // check for zero coefficients
{
    // find non-zero coefficient
    int swapRow = col + 1;
    for (; swapRow < rowCount; swapRow++) if (M[swapRow, col] != 0) break;

    if (M[swapRow, col] != 0) // found a non-zero coefficient?
    {
        // yes, then swap it with the above
        double tmp[2];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++)
        {
            tmp[i] = M[swapRow][i];
            M[swapRow][i] = M[col][i];
            M[col][i] = tmp[i];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\n the matrix has no unique solution";
        return; // no, then the matrix has no unique solution
    }
}

// elimination
for (int sourceRow = 0; sourceRow + 1 < rowCount; sourceRow++)
{
    for (int destRow = sourceRow + 1; destRow < rowCount; destRow++)
    {
        double df = M[sourceRow][sourceRow];
        double sf = M[destRow][sourceRow];
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++)
            M[destRow][i] = M[destRow][i] * df - M[sourceRow][i] * sf;
    }
}

// back-insertion
for (int row = rowCount - 1; row >= 0; row--)
{
    double f = M[row][row];
    if (f == 0) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++) M[row][i] /= f;
    for (int destRow = 0; destRow < row; destRow++)
    {
        M[destRow][rowCount] -= M[destRow][row] * M[row][rowCount]; M[destRow][row] = 0;
    }
}



double n = M[0][2];
double m = M[1][2];
Vector3D i1 = { p1.x + (m * d1.x), p1.y + (m * d1.y), p1.z + (m * d1.z) };
Vector3D i2 = { p3.x + (n * d2.x), p3.y + (n * d2.y), p3.z + (n * d2.z) };
Vector3D i1Clamped = ClampPointToLine(i1, p1, p2);
Vector3D i2Clamped = ClampPointToLine(i2, p3, p4);
ClosestPointOnLineP1P2 = i1Clamped;
ClosestPointOnLineP3P4 = i2Clamped;
return;
}
```

Comment: You have very confusing notations. Why `AB1` is a point/vector? Usually `AB` means a line segment between two points `A` and `B`.  And what `AB1CD` even supposed to mean? Why is it also a 3d point? I  very confused.

Comment: Sorry if the notions are a bit confusing let me explain, `AB1CD` means From Point AB1 to Line CD(not segment) Please visit for [Visual Representation](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/np6fgkxp)

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38640244/8359552) answer. It's c# but since you seem to have a math problem, this explains how to solve it.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40234003/3d-line-intersection-code-not-working-properly/40236124#40236124) describes finding closest distance between two skew lines. You can apply this approach to your segments, find parameters s,t of closest points for both segments. If these parameters lie in range of segment lengths, closest points are on segments, otherwise choose corresponding segment ends.

Comment: @MBo Unfortunately that is 2D line segment...

Comment: @Punal Manalan Emm.. My answer there is for 3D

Comment: @StefanKssmr I have tried that link Converted code from c# to C++ but is giving me the Wrong answer `Updated CODE in Question`
AB1 = (-7.54, 6.55, 0 ),
AB2 = (-3.87, 4.54, 6.0 ),
CD1 = (0.0, 8.0, 3.53 ),
CD2 = (0.03, -7.24, -1.34 ),
Return1 =  (-4.372801, 4.815376, 5.177982 ),
Return2 = (0.004745, 5.589532, 2.759726 )

Comment: @MBo my Mistake, but i don't understand what language the code is written in... Could you please write it in terms of C++

Comment: @PunalManalan I'll have a look at it. What is the correct answer?

Comment: [Page linked in that answer](http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/) gives links to code in c and c# .

Comment: @StefanKssmr 
Point1 = (0.01, 1.59, 1.48 ),  
Point2 = (-1.23, 1.11, 3.13 )
Please [Visit this](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/np6fgkxp) For Visual Representation

Comment: @MBo I Will be trying it now! Thanks

Comment: Also visit site geometrictools.com - there is powerful 2D/3D geometry library, I think you can find appropriate function in `distance` chapter

Comment: @MBo Let me look into it, Thanks!

Comment: @PunalManalan Your input is incorrect: you use AB2 = (-3.87, 4.54, 6.0 ) but at the linked page you use AB2 = (4.54, -3.87, 6.0 )

Comment: @StefanKssmr oh sorry I meant to change it before it was 5 minute edit time was already over!
But the Point1,Point2 are correct.
also can you please look into this code? This said code does not work when Both the linesegments are in the same Plane...

Comment: @PunalManalan I tested the original code which gives P1=P2 when both lines are in the same plane [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/sfzo1fdYf). It gives the same result as my code (not surprising as both are based on the same mathematical foundation).

Comment: @StefanKssmr then Is there no way to get the correct Points?

Comment: What do you mean by 'correct points'? I think the ones returned by the c algorithm are correct. If both lines are in the same plane they'll have an intersection if they are not parallel. This is excactly what the algorithm returns (P1=P2).

Comment: @StefanKssmr That is correct Points **IF** they Line, but they are actually _Line Segments_ so they are incorrect...

Comment: @PunalManalan As I explained in my answer below, computing the shortest connection between to lines is only one part of the puzzle. If P1 and/or P2 are not in your segments you have to check the shortest connections of a segments endpoints and the corresponding line. If none of these points are contained in the segments, your shortest connection must be one of the segments connecting two endpoints of your segements.

Comment: @StefanKssmr So if the Points are not on the segment then I have to, calculate Shortest Points on Opposite Line segments from the 4 points...
and calculate Which resultant point has the least Magnitude
right?

Comment: @MBo I have visited geometrictools.com and Unfortunately, I Didn't understand all those Unfamiliar code complex fully...

Comment: @PunalManalan see the last edit I made in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre Thank you very much for showing your code! but unfortunately, But I am already using a tinkered(by me to make it "compact") version of StefanKssmr 's code

Comment: @PunalManalan no problem he pointed me in here and I just wanted to acknowledge the fix to a problem (he found) in my code as it was used in here ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is to find the shortest connection `P1P2` between two line segments `AB` and `CD`. Let us define `l1` as the line which goes through the points `A` and `B` and `l2` as the line which goes through `C` and `D`.

You can split this problem up into several subtasks:

- finding the shortest connection between the lines `l1` and `l2`.
- finding the shortest connection from either of the points `A`, `B` to segment `CD` (likewise for `C`,`D` to segment `AB`).

Let's start with the first subtask. THe line `l1`, going through `A` and `B`, can be parametrised by a single scalar, say `sc`,

```
l1(sc) = u*sc + A
```

with the direction vector `u=(B-A)`.
As a consequence, we also have `l1(0) = A` and `l(1) = B`. Now, we want to find the minimal distance between this line and another line going through `C` and `D`, i.e.

```
l2(c) = v*tc + C
```

with `v = D-C`. In analogy to the other line, we have have `l2(0) = C` and `l(1) = D`. Now, we define

```
f(sc, tc) = 1/2*|l1(sc)-l2(tc)|^2
```

which is nothing but half the distance between the two lines squared. If we now want to minimise this function, we need to satisfy

```
df/dsc = 0 and df/dtc = 0
```

You'll find that

```
df/dsc = [u*sc - v*tc + (A-C)]*u    and    df/dtc = [u*sc - v*tc + (A-C)]*(-v)
```

Introducing `w=A-C` and arranging in vectors and matrices yields:

```
[ u*u    -v*u] *   [sc]  = -[ w*u] 
[-u*v     v*v]     [tc]     [-w*v]

      m        *  result = -rhs
```

The solution of the linear system is `result = -m^(⁻1)* rhs`, where `m^(⁻1)` is the inverse of `m`. If `a` and `c` are less than 0 or greater than 1, the closest point of the lines is outside the segments `AB` and `CD`. You might return these values as well.

The second subtask is closely related to this problem, but we minimise

```
f(sc) = 1/2*|l1(sc)-P|^2   and   g(tc) = 1/2*|l2(tc)-P|^2
```

which directly yields

```
sc = -(A-P)*u/(u*u)    and   rc = -(C-P)*v/(v*v)
```

If `sc < 0` we set `sc = 0` or if `sc > 1` we set `sc = 1` (and likewise for `tc`) in order to get points on the segments.

Here is the implementation, which I took from [here](http://geomalgorithms.com/a07-_distance.html#dist3D_Segment_to_Segment()) and modified it.
First, we define some helpers, i.e. vectors and some basic mathematical relations.

```
template <int dim>
struct Vector
{
    std::array<double, dim> components; 
};


using Vector2D = Vector<2>;
using Vector3D = Vector<3>;


// subtract
template <int dim>
Vector<dim> operator-(const Vector<dim> &u, const Vector<dim> &v) {
    Vector<dim> result(u);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        result.components[i] -= v.components[i];
    return result;
}

// add
template <int dim>
Vector<dim> operator+(const Vector<dim> &u, const Vector<dim> &v) {
    Vector<dim> result(u);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        result.components[i] += v.components[i];
    return result;
}

// negate
template <int dim>
Vector<dim> operator-(const Vector<dim> &u) {
    Vector<dim> result;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        result.components[i] = -u.components[i];
    return result;
}

// scalar product
template <int dim>
double operator*(const Vector<dim> &u, const Vector<dim> &v) {
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        result += u.components[i] * v.components[i];
    return result;
}

// scale
template <int dim>
Vector<dim> operator*(const Vector<dim> &u, const double s) {
    Vector<dim> result(u);
    for (int i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        result.components[i] *= s;
    return result;
}

// scale
template <int dim>
Vector<dim> operator*(const double s, const Vector<dim> &u) {
    return u*s;
}


// ostream
template <int dim>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const Vector<dim> &u) {
    out << "(";
    for (auto c : u.components)
        out << std::setw(15) << c ;
    out << ")";
    return out;
}
```

This function does the actual work:

```
std::pair<Vector3D, Vector3D>
shortest_connection_segment_to_segment(const Vector3D A, const Vector3D B,
                                       const Vector3D C, const Vector3D D)
{
    Vector3D u = B - A;
    Vector3D v = D - C;
    Vector3D w = A - C;

    double    a = u*u;         // always >= 0
    double    b = u*v;
    double    c = v*v;         // always >= 0
    double    d = u*w;
    double    e = v*w;
    double    sc, sN, sD = a*c - b*b;  // sc = sN / sD, sD >= 0
    double    tc, tN, tD = a*c - b*b;  // tc = tN / tD, tD >= 0
    double    tol = 1e-15;
    // compute the line parameters of the two closest points
    if (sD < tol) {            // the lines are almost parallel
        sN = 0.0;              // force using point A on segment AB
        sD = 1.0;              // to prevent possible division by 0.0 later
        tN = e;
        tD = c;
    }
    else {                     // get the closest points on the infinite lines
        sN = (b*e - c*d);
        tN = (a*e - b*d);
        if (sN < 0.0) {        // sc < 0 => the s=0 edge is visible
            sN = 0.0;          // compute shortest connection of A to segment CD
            tN = e;
            tD = c;
        }
        else if (sN > sD) {    // sc > 1  => the s=1 edge is visible
            sN = sD;           // compute shortest connection of B to segment CD
            tN = e + b;
            tD = c;
        }
    }

    if (tN < 0.0) {            // tc < 0 => the t=0 edge is visible
        tN = 0.0;             
        // recompute sc for this edge
        if (-d < 0.0)          // compute shortest connection of C to segment AB
            sN = 0.0;
        else if (-d > a)
            sN = sD;
        else {
            sN = -d;
            sD = a;
        }
    }
    else if (tN > tD) {      // tc > 1  => the t=1 edge is visible
        tN = tD;
        // recompute sc for this edge
        if ((-d + b) < 0.0)  // compute shortest connection of D to segment AB
            sN = 0;
        else if ((-d + b) > a)
            sN = sD;
        else {
            sN = (-d +  b);
            sD = a;
        }
    }
    // finally do the division to get sc and tc
    sc = (fabs(sN) < tol ? 0.0 : sN / sD);
    tc = (fabs(tN) < tol ? 0.0 : tN / tD);

    Vector3D P1 = A + (sc * u);
    Vector3D P2 = C + (tc * v);  

    return {P1, P2};   // return the closest distance
}
```

Usage:

```
int main() {

    Vector3D A = {-7.54, 6.55, 0 };
    Vector3D B = {4.54, -3.87, 6.0 };
    Vector3D C = {0.0, 8.0, 3.53 };
    Vector3D D = {0.03, -7.24, -1.34 };

    auto [P1, P2] = shortest_connection_segment_to_segment (A, B, C, D);

    std::cout << "P1 = " << P1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "P2 = " << P2 << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
P1 = (       -1.24635         1.1212        3.12599)
P2 = (      0.0125125        1.64365        1.49881)
```

[live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G9K71qEG5).

**Note that this code still requires more testing.**

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer, I gave you +1(but it did not show as I have only 13 rep...) 

but I already have the Exact same function as this which has the same problem like this one...
i.e it does not work when both line segments are on the Same Plane(Parallel) and
the points returned may or may not line on the Line segment but on Infinite Line...

So my question is Should I use Another function together when this Fails(Parallel or Outside segment) 
Should i use this function NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfVariedLength() **Look for Code in Question**

Thanks!

Comment: @PunalManalan Just to clarify, "on the same plane" does not mean "parallel". That confused me a lot. Yes, when the points you found lie outside of the segments you have to use another function which. NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfVariedLength() and the function inside it looks promising but very confusing tbh, especially the argument names. Therefore I haven't checked it in detail.

Comment: If both functions are combined it would work! Also sorry for confusing you
In my last comment, i was running out of space... so I had to use Plane(Parallel) instead of  " or "
Also could you please update your answer with NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegmentOfVariedLength() or similar so that i can Mark your answer as the accepted one!

Comment: @PunalManalan Done

Answer (score -1):

Below Is a "Compact" version of the code from @StefanKssmr which is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984315/12500521), This "Compact" version can easily be ported to OpenCL

Many thanks to @StefanKssmr for posting the Correct Answer,

```
void NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegment(Vector3D AB1, Vector3D AB2, Vector3D CD1, Vector3D CD2, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint1, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint2)
{
Vector3D u = VectorMinus(AB2, AB1);
Vector3D v = VectorMinus(CD2, CD1);
Vector3D w = VectorMinus(AB1, CD1);

double    a = DotProduct(u, u);         // always >= 0
double    b = DotProduct(u, v);
double    c = DotProduct(v, v);         // always >= 0
double    d = DotProduct(u, w);
double    e = DotProduct(v, w);
double    sN, sD = (a * c) - (b * b);  // sc = sN / sD, default sD = D >= 0
double    tN, tD = (a * c) - (b * b);  // tc = tN / tD, default tD = D >= 0

float Temp1;
float Temp2;
float Temp3;// Unfortuantely i have no choice but to use this...

//Part 1
Temp1 = (sD < 1e-6f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
sN = (1.0f - Temp1) * (b * e - c * d);
sD = ((1.0f - Temp1) * sD) + Temp1;
tN = (Temp1 * e) +  ((1.0f - Temp1) * ((a * e) - (b * d)));
tD = (Temp1 * c) + ((1.0f - Temp1) * tD);

Temp2 = (sN < 0.0f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
Temp2 = Temp2 * (1.0f - Temp1);
sN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN);
tN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tN) + (Temp2 * e);
tD = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tD) + (Temp2 * c);

Temp2 = ((sN > sD) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp2);
Temp2 = Temp2 * (1.0f - Temp1);
sN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN) + (Temp2 * sD);
tN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tN) + (Temp2 * (e + b));
tD = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tD) + (Temp2 * c);

//Part 2.1
Temp1 = (tN < 0.0f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
tN = tN * (1.0f - Temp1);

Temp2 = (((-d) < 0.0) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * Temp1;
sN = (1.0f - Temp2) * sN;//sN = (Temp2 * 0) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN);    
Temp3 = ((((-d) > a) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp2)) * (Temp1);
sN = (Temp3 * sD) + ((1.0f - Temp3) * (sN));

Temp2 = (1.0f - Temp3) * (1.0f - Temp2) * (Temp1);
sN = (Temp2 * (-d)) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sN));
sD = (Temp2 * a) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sD));

//Part 2.2
Temp1 = ((tN > tD) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp1);
tN = ((1.0f - Temp1) * tN) + (Temp1 * tD);

Temp2 = (((-d + b) < 0.0) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * Temp1;
sN = (1.0f - Temp2) * sN;//sN = (Temp2 * 0) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN);    
Temp3 = ((((-d + b) > a) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp2)) * (Temp1);
sN = (Temp3 * sD) + ((1.0f - Temp3) * (sN));

Temp2 = (1.0f - Temp3) * (1.0f - Temp2) * (Temp1);
sN = (Temp2 * (-d)) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sN));
sD = (Temp2 * a) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sD));

resultSegmentPoint1 = VectorAdd(AB1, VectorMultiply(u, (fabs(sN) < 1e-6f ? 0.0 : sN / sD)));
resultSegmentPoint2 = VectorAdd(CD1, VectorMultiply(v, (fabs(tN) < 1e-6f ? 0.0 : tN / tD)));
}
```

Comment: I am afraid this is not correct. First, in `t0 = (t1 < 0.0) ? ...` the check of `t1` look suspicious. Second, please test against the following points: `AB1={1,1,0}`, `AB2={2,3,0}`, `CD1={2,1,0}`, CD2={2,-2,0}. If `VectorMinus`, `DotProduct`, etc behave as expected, your code gives `{1,1,0}` and `{2,1,0}` (distance = 1). If you compare it with the algorithm of the source I referred to, you will get `{1.2, 1.4, 0}` and `{2,1,0}` (distance = 0.894427). See [this](https://godbolt.org/z/74d953vd3) comparison.

Comment: Even if you change the suspicious line I mentioned to `t0 = (t0 < 0.0) ? ...`, you will get an incorrect result (`{2,3,0}` and `{2,1,0}`, distance = 2). You are missing some of the corner cases here. I did this error myself, hence the numerous edits of my answer. You can easily draw the test case I posted above on a sheet of paper and check the results yourself, it is basically 2D as z=0.

Comment: @StefanKssmr Once again Thanks a lot for helping me!
Let me replace the code with yours but i will slightly modify the code to make it "Compact"

Comment: @StefanKssmr I have now properly made a "compact" version from your answer, Here is the Online the Code in [Online compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/5351WxGn9)