# Closest Two 3D Point between A Line Segment And Plane defined And Restricted within by Three Points(3D triangle Polygon)

Tags: c++, math, vector, 3d, plane

Let's say `A1&A2` are **Two** 3D points that make a line Segment.

`T1,T2,T3` are **Three** 3D points that make a Triangle Polygon in 3D space.

Let `P1` be a point on the Line segment, Let `P2` be a point on the Triangle Polygon

`P1` And `P2` Are Closest To each other

Now, how can I Calculate `P1` and `P2` which method shall I use?

Right now *I know* how to find the closest point on a line segment from a point.

and Closest two Points between **Two** Line Segment.

I use this Below Function to find the closest line segment between two line segment

```
std::pair<Vector3D, Vector3D>
shortest_connection_segment_to_segment(const Vector3D A, const Vector3D B,
                                   const Vector3D C, const Vector3D D)
{
Vector3D u = B - A;
Vector3D v = D - C;
Vector3D w = A - C;

double    a = u*u;         // always >= 0
double    b = u*v;
double    c = v*v;         // always >= 0
double    d = u*w;
double    e = v*w;
double    sc, sN, sD = a*c - b*b;  // sc = sN / sD, sD >= 0
double    tc, tN, tD = a*c - b*b;  // tc = tN / tD, tD >= 0
double    tol = 1e-15;
// compute the line parameters of the two closest points
if (sD < tol) {            // the lines are almost parallel
    sN = 0.0;              // force using point A on segment AB
    sD = 1.0;              // to prevent possible division by 0.0 later
    tN = e;
    tD = c;
}
else {                     // get the closest points on the infinite lines
    sN = (b*e - c*d);
    tN = (a*e - b*d);
    if (sN < 0.0) {        // sc < 0 => the s=0 edge is visible
        sN = 0.0;          // compute shortest connection of A to segment CD
        tN = e;
        tD = c;
    }
    else if (sN > sD) {    // sc > 1  => the s=1 edge is visible
        sN = sD;           // compute shortest connection of B to segment CD
        tN = e + b;
        tD = c;
    }
}

if (tN < 0.0) {            // tc < 0 => the t=0 edge is visible
    tN = 0.0;             
    // recompute sc for this edge
    if (-d < 0.0)          // compute shortest connection of C to segment AB
        sN = 0.0;
    else if (-d > a)
        sN = sD;
    else {
        sN = -d;
        sD = a;
    }
}
else if (tN > tD) {      // tc > 1  => the t=1 edge is visible
    tN = tD;
    // recompute sc for this edge
    if ((-d + b) < 0.0)  // compute shortest connection of D to segment AB
        sN = 0;
    else if ((-d + b) > a)
        sN = sD;
    else {
        sN = (-d +  b);
        sD = a;
    }
}
// finally do the division to get sc and tc
sc = (fabs(sN) < tol ? 0.0 : sN / sD);
tc = (fabs(tN) < tol ? 0.0 : tN / tD);

Vector3D P1 = A + (sc * u);
Vector3D P2 = C + (tc * v);  

return {P1, P2};   // return the closest distance
}
```

Comment: Seems to me like this is more for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/

Comment: see [`line closest(line l0,triangle t0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62257945/2521214)

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for showing me this link! I will try to use the code there and write a minimal version of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function Below Gets the Closest 2 3D points(line segment) between a Triangle(defined by 3 points) and a Line Segment(Defined by 2 points). These math functions are based on [@StefanKssmr 's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66984315/12500521) And [@Spektre 's line closest(line l0,triangle t0)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62257945/revisions). Here is the Entire Code [Online Compiler](https://godbolt.org/z/7raKEbd5b) with Example.
Here is the [Visual Representation](https://www.geogebra.org/3d/cbb9sknj) for the examples

```
void ClosestPointBetweenTriangleAndLineSegment(Vector3D LineStart, Vector3D LineEnd, Vector3D Triangle0, Vector3D Triangle1, Vector3D Triangle2, Vector3D& ClosestPointOnLine, Vector3D& ClosestPointOnTriangle)
{
    ClosestPointOnLine = LineStart;//For FirstPart Calculation Only
    ClosestPointOnTriangle;
    Vector3D Return1 = LineEnd;//For FirstPart Calculation Only
    Vector3D Return2;
    NearestPointBetweenPointAndPlane(ClosestPointOnLine, Triangle0, Triangle1, Triangle2, ClosestPointOnTriangle);

    NearestPointBetweenPointAndPlane(Return1, Triangle0, Triangle1, Triangle2, Return2);

    if (Magnitude(VectorMinus(Return1, Return2)) < Magnitude(VectorMinus(ClosestPointOnLine, ClosestPointOnTriangle)))
    {
        ClosestPointOnLine = Return1;
        ClosestPointOnTriangle = Return2;
    }

    if (FastNoCheckIsPointWithinTraingle(ClosestPointOnTriangle, Triangle0, Triangle1, Triangle2))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegment(LineStart, LineEnd, Triangle0, Triangle1, ClosestPointOnLine, ClosestPointOnTriangle);// Only For First
        NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegment(LineStart, LineEnd, Triangle0, Triangle2, Return1, Return2);
        if (Magnitude(VectorMinus(Return1, Return2)) < Magnitude(VectorMinus(ClosestPointOnLine, ClosestPointOnTriangle)))
        {
            ClosestPointOnLine = Return1;
            ClosestPointOnTriangle = Return2;
        }
        NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegment(LineStart, LineEnd, Triangle1, Triangle2, Return1, Return2);
        if (Magnitude(VectorMinus(Return1, Return2)) < Magnitude(VectorMinus(ClosestPointOnLine, ClosestPointOnTriangle)))
        {
            ClosestPointOnLine = Return1;
            ClosestPointOnTriangle = Return2;
        }
    }
}
```

**Below are the Helper Function for the above function All are based on common math**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

struct Vector3D
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
};

struct Vector4D
{
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    float z = 0;
    float d = 0;
};

Vector3D VectorAdd(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2)
{
    return { V1.x + V2.x, V1.y + V2.y, V1.z + V2.z };
}

Vector3D VectorMinus(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2)
{
    return { V1.x - V2.x, V1.y - V2.y, V1.z - V2.z };
}
    
Vector3D VectorMultiply(Vector3D V1, float Multiplier)
{
    return { (V1.x * Multiplier), (V1.y * Multiplier), (V1.z * Multiplier) };
}

Vector3D VectorMultiplyVector(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2)
{
    return { (V1.x * V2.x), (V1.y * V2.y), (V1.z * V2.z) };
}

Vector3D VectorDivide(Vector3D V1, float Divider)
{
    return{ (V1.x / Divider), (V1.y / Divider), (V1.z / Divider) };
}

float DotProduct(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2)
{
    return (float)(V1.x * V2.x) + (V1.y * V2.y) + (V1.z * V2.z);
}

Vector3D CrossProduct(Vector3D V1, Vector3D V2)
{
    return { (V1.y * V2.z) - (V1.z * V2.y),
             (V1.z * V2.x) - (V1.x * V2.z),
             (V1.x * V2.y) - (V1.y * V2.x) };
}

Vector3D VectorPower(Vector3D V1, float Power)
{
    return { pow(V1.x, Power), pow(V1.y, Power), pow(V1.z, Power) };
}

float VectorTotal(Vector3D V1)
{
    return DotProduct(V1, { 1,1,1 });
}

float Magnitude(Vector3D Vector)
{
    float CalculationFloat = (float)(sqrt(pow(Vector.x, 2.0) + pow(Vector.y, 2.0) + pow(Vector.z, 2.0)));
    if (std::isnan(CalculationFloat) || std::isinf(CalculationFloat))
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return CalculationFloat;
}

float AreaOfTriangle3D(Vector3D VA, Vector3D VB, Vector3D VC)
{
    return Magnitude(CrossProduct(VectorMinus(VB, VA), VectorMinus(VC, VA))) / 2;
}

void NearestPointBetweenTwoLineSegment(Vector3D AB1, Vector3D AB2, Vector3D CD1, Vector3D CD2, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint1, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint2)
{
    Vector3D u = VectorMinus(AB2, AB1);
    Vector3D v = VectorMinus(CD2, CD1);
    Vector3D w = VectorMinus(AB1, CD1);

    double    a = DotProduct(u, u);         // always >= 0
    double    b = DotProduct(u, v);
    double    c = DotProduct(v, v);         // always >= 0
    double    d = DotProduct(u, w);
    double    e = DotProduct(v, w);
    double    sN, sD = (a * c) - (b * b);  // sc = sN / sD, default sD = D >= 0
    double    tN, tD = (a * c) - (b * b);  // tc = tN / tD, default tD = D >= 0

    float Temp1;
    float Temp2;
    float Temp3;// Unfortuantely i have no choice but to use this...

    //Part 1
    Temp1 = (sD < 1e-6f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    sN = (1.0f - Temp1) * (b * e - c * d);
    sD = ((1.0f - Temp1) * sD) + Temp1;
    tN = (Temp1 * e) + ((1.0f - Temp1) * ((a * e) - (b * d)));
    tD = (Temp1 * c) + ((1.0f - Temp1) * tD);

    Temp2 = (sN < 0.0f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    Temp2 = Temp2 * (1.0f - Temp1);
    sN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN);
    tN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tN) + (Temp2 * e);
    tD = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tD) + (Temp2 * c);

    Temp2 = ((sN > sD) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp2);
    Temp2 = Temp2 * (1.0f - Temp1);
    sN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN) + (Temp2 * sD);
    tN = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tN) + (Temp2 * (e + b));
    tD = ((1.0f - Temp2) * tD) + (Temp2 * c);

    //Part 2.1
    Temp1 = (tN < 0.0f) ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
    tN = tN * (1.0f - Temp1);

    Temp2 = (((-d) < 0.0) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * Temp1;
    sN = (1.0f - Temp2) * sN;//sN = (Temp2 * 0) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN);    
    Temp3 = ((((-d) > a) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp2)) * (Temp1);
    sN = (Temp3 * sD) + ((1.0f - Temp3) * (sN));

    Temp2 = (1.0f - Temp3) * (1.0f - Temp2) * (Temp1);
    sN = (Temp2 * (-d)) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sN));
    sD = (Temp2 * a) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sD));

    //Part 2.2
    Temp1 = ((tN > tD) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp1);
    tN = ((1.0f - Temp1) * tN) + (Temp1 * tD);

    Temp2 = (((-d + b) < 0.0) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * Temp1;
    sN = (1.0f - Temp2) * sN;//sN = (Temp2 * 0) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * sN);    
    Temp3 = ((((-d + b) > a) ? 1.0f : 0.0f) * (1.0f - Temp2)) * (Temp1);
    sN = (Temp3 * sD) + ((1.0f - Temp3) * (sN));

    Temp2 = (1.0f - Temp3) * (1.0f - Temp2) * (Temp1);
    sN = (Temp2 * (-d)) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sN));
    sD = (Temp2 * a) + ((1.0f - Temp2) * (sD));

    resultSegmentPoint1 = VectorAdd(AB1, VectorMultiply(u, (fabs(sN) < 1e-6f ? 0.0 : sN / sD)));
    resultSegmentPoint2 = VectorAdd(CD1, VectorMultiply(v, (fabs(tN) < 1e-6f ? 0.0 : tN / tD)));
}

bool FastNoCheckIsPointWithinTraingle(Vector3D Point, Vector3D Triangle0, Vector3D Triangle1, Vector3D Triangle2)
{
    return fabsf((AreaOfTriangle3D(Point, Triangle1, Triangle2) + AreaOfTriangle3D(Triangle0, Point, Triangle2) + AreaOfTriangle3D(Triangle0, Triangle1, Point)) - AreaOfTriangle3D(Triangle0, Triangle1, Triangle2)) < 1.0f;
}

Vector4D equation_plane(float x1, float y1,
    float z1, float x2,
    float y2, float z2,
    float x3, float y3, float z3)
{
    float a1 = x2 - x1;
    float b1 = y2 - y1;
    float c1 = z2 - z1;
    float a2 = x3 - x1;
    float b2 = y3 - y1;
    float c2 = z3 - z1;
    float a = b1 * c2 - b2 * c1;
    float b = a2 * c1 - a1 * c2;
    float c = a1 * b2 - b1 * a2;
    float d = (-a * x1 - b * y1 - c * z1);
    //std::cout << std::fixed;
    //std::cout << std::setprecision(2);
    std::cout << "\nequation of plane is " << a << " x + " << b << " y + " << c << " z + ";
    printf("%f", d);
    std::cout << " = 0.";
    return { a,b,c,d };
}

void NearestPointBetweenPointAndPlane(Vector3D Point, Vector3D Triangle0, Vector3D Triangle1, Vector3D Triangle2, Vector3D& resultSegmentPoint)
{
    //Note: Plane equation is x + y + z + d = 0 format// 
    Vector4D Plane = equation_plane(Triangle0.x, Triangle0.y, Triangle0.z, Triangle1.x, Triangle1.y, Triangle1.z, Triangle2.x, Triangle2.y, Triangle2.z);
    Vector3D PlanePartial;
    PlanePartial.x = Plane.x;
    PlanePartial.y = Plane.y;
    PlanePartial.z = Plane.z;
    resultSegmentPoint = VectorAdd(Point, VectorMultiply(PlanePartial, -((VectorTotal(VectorMultiplyVector(Point, PlanePartial)) + Plane.d) / VectorTotal(VectorPower(PlanePartial, 2)))));
}
```

**Optional Debug Function**

```
int Clamp(double Number, double Min, double Max)
{
    if (Number > Max)
    {
        return Max;
    }
    if (Number < Min)
    {
        return Min;
    }
    return Number;
}

void PrintVector3Dfor(Vector3D Point, std::string Name, bool InvertXY)
{
    int SpaceBar = 50;
    SpaceBar = Clamp(SpaceBar - Name.length(), 0, 50);
    std::cout << "\n" << Name << " =";
    for (int i = 0; i < SpaceBar; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "(";
    if (InvertXY)
    {
        printf("%f", Point.y);
        printf(", %f", Point.x);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%f", Point.x);
        printf(", %f", Point.y);
    }

    printf(", %f )", Point.z);
}

void Printfloatfor(float val, std::string Name)
{
    int SpaceBar = 50;
    SpaceBar = Clamp(SpaceBar - Name.length(), 0, 50);
    std::cout << "\n" << Name << " =";
    for (int i = 0; i < SpaceBar; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << " ";
    }
    printf(" %f", val);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could spend a lot of time writing and debugging quite a lot of code if you do this 'by hand'. A better approach would be to formulate it as an instance of a general problem and then look for libraries that can solve this problem.

In this case the problem is 'constrained linear least squares' which is quite common.

The first thing to do is to introduce parameters, for example:

A point P on the line is given by

```
P = P1 + l*(P2-P1) where 0<=l<=1
```

A point T in the triangle is given by

```
T = T1 + s*(T2-T1) + t*(T3-T1) 
where 0<=s<=1 and 0<=t<=1 and s+t<=1
```

The objective function is the distance squared between P and T, i.e.

```
d2 = ||P(l) - T(s,t)||^2
```

A little algebra casts this into the standard least squares form:

```
d2 = ||A*x - b ||^2 where
x = (l,s,t)'
A = (P2-P1  T1-T2  T1-T3)
b = T1-P1
and the constraints, as above, are
0<=l and l<=1
0<=s and s<=1
0<=t and t<=1
s+t <= 1
```

Comment: @dnuir Thanks for posting! can you please elaborate on the last part, I could not understand it fully sorry